# Media query for safari browser

Tags: css

I want the media to work only on safari for a screen of 1280px

This work in all browser, but i want only safari

```
@media screen and (width: 1280px){


}
```

Answer (score 12):

**Try this**

**Webkit:Chrome & Safari (any version)**

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
property: value;}
```

**Chrome 29+**

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) {
.chrome {
    property: value;
}}
```

**Safari (7.1+)**

```
_::-webkit-full-page-media, _:future, :root .safari_only {
property: value;}
```

**Safari (from 6.1 to 10.0)**

```
@media screen and (min-color-index:0) and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
@media {
    /* Your Class */
}}
```

**Safari (10.1+)**

```
@media not all and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) { 
@media {
    /* Your Class */
}}
```

USEFUL LINKS:[browser specific CSS and JavaScript hacks](http://browserhacks.com/)

Comment: doesn't the safari 7.1+ encompass the safari 10.1+ ? or you wanted to write safari [7.1 to 10.0] ?

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use JavaScript:

Here's an snippet to try this detection

```js
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('safari/') > -1 && screen.width=="1280px") {
  console.log("True")
}else {
  document.getElementById("a").display = "none"
  console.log("False")
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p id="a">Safari mobile<p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't know how to get if media type is screen on CSS.

Comment: Best to use this approach, CSS is a stylesheet and isn't used for the approach OP is requiring.

Comment: Totally agree @OliverHeward .

Comment: Let the programming languages handle that stuff, leave CSS to deal with what it knows best haha :)

Answer (score -11):

try this:

```
@media only screen and (width: 1280px) {


}
```

Comment: Your answer is currently marked as low quality and faces deletion. Please make sure your answer contains an explanation aside from any code.

Comment: This is applied to any browser