# How to have a fallback background-image using image-set without javascript?

Tags: css

I am fairly new to the frontend and css. I am trying to add a `background-image` in such a way that, if `.avif` files are supported, then these are loaded. Otherwise fallback to a `.png` file. I'm wondering if it is possible to do this without javascript and without loading all the images to not affect page speed. I am running `Chrome 107.0.5304.110`, `ios 16.1` in (mostly)simulator (I know older versions of ios dont support avif, but the latest one does. Would like something that works with both) , and Firefox `106.0.1`.

[Attempt 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64350281/1462297) follows this previous answer. Note the usage of `webkit-image-set`. Here is my code:

```
background-image: url("/static/img/image.png");
background-image: -webkit-image-set(url("/static/img/image.avif")1x );
```

Doing this works for Chrome and Firefox, but Safari on ios shows a gray image.

[Attempt 2](https://raoulkramer.de/avif-webp-images-css-background-usage-progressive-enhanced-with-image-set/) follows the answer on this blog. Note that here `image-set` is used. Code:

```
background-image: url("/static/img/image.png");
background-image: image-set(
  url("/static/img/image.avif") 1x,
  url("/static/img/image.png") 1x,
);
```

This is visible on all three browsers, but the png is always shown. I also invert the positions in the image-set but same results. Always png.

Attempt 3, a slight variation of attempt 2. I just change the format on the first line.

```
background-image: url("/static/img/image.avif");
background-image: image-set(
  url("/static/img/image.avif") 1x,
  url("/static/img/image.png") 1x,
);
```

This works well on chrome/firefox, but ios is gray.

Is there a way to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Look CSS engine if he found two properties the same he would take the last one

Answer (score 1):

It seem's that `image-set` are partially supported on Safari browsers,

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image/image-set#browser_compatibility)

[caniuse](https://caniuse.com/css-image-set)

You can simply use

```css
background-image: 
    url("/static/img/image.avif"),
    url("/static/img/image.jpeg");
```

you can test on sandbox below that on Firefox avif is used and on safari jpg is used as fallback.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-benji-o4u93v?file=/styles.css)

As [MDN usage examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image/image-set#examples) there's no inbuilt fallback for image-set(), therefore putting an background-image before.

```css
.box {
  background-image: url("large-balloons.jpg");
  background-image: image-set(
    "large-balloons.avif" type("image/avif"),
    "large-balloons.jpg" type("image/jpeg")
  );
}
```

also as you can see above the example uses type param, which safari doesn't support.

Another solution you can use is to have @media selectors specifically for safari and put specific code for this browser there:
[Media query for safari browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62874933/media-query-for-safari-browser)

Comment: Yup... Do you know how I could work around this? Or is going with js the only way?

Comment: See the updated answer above.

Comment: This does provide a fallback. However, if I check out the network tab both images are loaded. Is there a way to only load avif if avif is supported without loading heavier jpeg, and the other way around?

Comment: Another solution you can use is to have @media selectors specifically for safari and put specific code for this browser there, just updated the answer with some links and examples;

Answer (score 0):

```
background-image: url("/static/img/image.avif"),url("/static/img/image.avif") 1x,url("/static/img/image.png") 1x;
```

Comment: Did you by chance miss the image-set there? Without image-set it doesnt work anywhere, with image-set it works on Firefox only.